# TO set background to a tabview in android

Tags: android

Can you please tell me how to set the background of a tabview in android?

Answer (score 0):

In the folder values, put :

```
<resources>
    <color name="green">#ff00ff00</color>
</resources>
```

in the colors.xml file.

In your java code :

```
tb.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green); //where tb is your tabview
```

If you want to do it in xml try :

```
android:background="@color/green"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but doing this the color is getting changed but the it is done on the background the tabs color remain the same....